# Python define duplicate rules

Tags: python

I have the following table:

```
index col_A col_B

0  John   Jones
1  Perez  Mark   
2  Jones  John   
3  Mark   Perez
4  Albert Perez
```

Rows 0 and 2 have the column values switched as well as rows 1 and 3. I am looking for a way to recognize rows 0 and 2 as duplicates and rows 1 and 3 as duplicates as well. Then I would like to drop the duplicates and keep only one of the unique occurrences. So the resulting matrix should be a 3 by 2 (since row 4 has no duplicates). Is there an efficient way to do this without using nested loops(my table has more than 3 millions rows)? Thanks

Comment: What database engine you are using?

Comment: @youngminz: It's a csv file

Comment: This would be efficient algorithm
 1: read all data into memory 2:Sort col_A and col_B 3) Sort datas ==> O(N log_2 N) 4) Find duplicates ==> O(N)

Comment: To find something duplicated, it would be efficient after sorting data. Nested for statement might be O(N^2) while sorting and finding duplicate is just O(N log_2 N) + O(N)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `set` to remember already added elements. Something like

```
a = [(0, 'John', 'Jones'), (1, 'Perez', 'Mark'), (2, 'Jones', 'John'), (3, 'Mark', 'Perez'), (4, 'Albert', 'Perez')]

res = []

already_added = set()

for e in a:
    key1, key2 = e[1]+e[2], e[2]+e[1]
    if key1 not in already_added and key2 not in already_added:
        res.append(e)
        already_added.add(key1)

res
Out[37]: [(0, 'John', 'Jones'), (1, 'Perez', 'Mark'), (4, 'Albert', 'Perez')]
```

Comment: Don't use `already_added |= set([key1])`, just use `already_added.add(key1)`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thanks for comment, I will correct my answer

Comment: @kvorobiev and juanpa.arrivillaga: Thanks! It works great. It took more than 15 mins, but I think it's the fastest option given the size of the table. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

A simple and most efficient way is to create a DBMS.
In sqlite3, something like this could work:

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT max(id) FROM table GROUP BY col_A,col_B)
```